# Sumproduct with mapping multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to write excel formula that will sum the values based on a match of the rows. The cells to be matched can occur multiple times and basing on the Mapping legend they should return the sum of values.

In the yellow cells I am trying to calculate sum of values in range B9:B21 based on a match of the names in G3:G8 according to Mapping legend to Item1, then Item2 and Item 3.
I got already answer on how to sum the values if array to be summed is the same as Mapping legend. But now my array to be summed in extended and SUMPRODUCT formula does not work anymore:

[image]

Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Your arrays are not of equal length which is why the above isn't working. Ordering would also become an issue.

Comment: Would you consider a simple vba function?

Comment: Can't you simplify by just adding an helper column in C10:C21 with an INDEX&MATCH formula, using a simple SUMIF formula after that?

Comment: Formula which can be used in `B3`, `B4` and `B5`:
`{=SUMPRODUCT(($A$10:$A$21=T(IF(TRANSPOSE($F$3:$F$8)=$A3,TRANSPOSE($G$3:$G$8))))*($B$10:$B$21))}` Posted only for curiosity. Helper columns really are the better solutions.

Comment: Alex Richter: Thanks It actually works good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs improving but is a starter user defined function that can be used in the sheet.

***function GetSum***

*arg1* ***item*** *String* The item to match against e.g. Item2

*arg2 **sourceData*** *Range* The data range to sum over according to item

*arg3 **lookup** Range* The data range containing the mapping (2 columns wide)

```
Public Function GetSum(ByVal item As String, sourceData As Range, lookup As Range) As Variant
    If lookup.Columns.Count <> 2 Then GetSum = CVErr(xlErrNA)

    Dim lookupDict As Object, arr(), arr2(), i As Long, finalValue As Double
    Set lookupDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If lookup.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim arr(1, 1)
        arr(1, 1) = lookup.Value
    Else
        arr = lookup.Value
    End If
    If sourceData.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim arr2(1, 1)
        arr2(1, 1) = sourceData.Value
    Else
        arr2 = sourceData.Value
    End If

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        lookupDict(arr(i, 2)) = arr(i, 1)
    Next i

    For i = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
        If lookupDict.exists(arr2(i, 1)) Then
            If lookupDict(arr2(i, 1)) = item Then
                finalValue = finalValue + arr2(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    GetSum = finalValue
End Function
```

---

Data:

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is the solution over the top I must say :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Fix your formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B11:B20,F6:F9,0)))),C11:C20)
```

As in the picture (can't change excel language sosad) :

[image]

As a general guideline for this an future projects, I would recommend as it's been said to use a **helper column** to tag your items and simplify the formula greatly :

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the mapping legend is must have as it will be stored in a separate sheet and no extra helper columns should bother Input values.

Comment: Precisely why I kept the mapping legend in the first part of my answer.
Then again you may consider using a helper column index(match())-ing with your legend mapping from another sheet as you will have to perfom more complex operations ! (+ it's better for auditability) ;) Have fun